# How to use torch::get_hash in libtorch?

Tags: c++, libtorch

I have been trying to get the hash of couple of modules in libtorch to no avail so far. In libtorch there are several hashing related functions such as :`get_hash` and `simple_hash_get` which are defined under `torch/csrc/utils/hash.h`.

I have tried to get a hash for my jit traced model like this:

```cpp
torch::jit::Module myModel;
myModel = torch::jit::load("mymodel.jit");
std::string module_hash = torch::get_hash(mymodel);
```

but this doesn't work.  I tried to get the underlying models representation which is in string(i.e. using `dump_to_str`) and pass it to `get_hash()`, that doesn't work either!  How can I use this functionality in libtorch?

### Note

I need to find a way other than using which may not be a good/reliable choice as it creates different hashes each time:

```cpp
auto model_hash = std::hash<std::string>{}(model_dumped_as_str)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to hash your modules ?

Comment: @trialNerror , I'm looking for a way to uniquely identify each object of mine. couldnt comeup with a better idea!